# How to stop NumLock toggling

Tags: kde, numlock, numpad

Is there any way to stop NumLock toggling keypad in KDE?

I want to use Numlock as a hotkey and toggle keypad with another key or with an application.

Answer (score 2):

1. Open nautilus with:

   `sudo nautilus`
2. Go to `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols`
3. Open `pc` file with gedit.
4. Change the line

   `key <NMLK> {   [ Num_Lock      ]   };`

To

```
key <NMLK> {    [XF86Bluetooth,       Num_Lock      ]   };
```

6. Save and close the file.

7. Run

   `sudo dpkg-reconfigure xkb-data`
8. Restart the computer.

Now you will be able to use NumLock as a hotkey.

Also check this, in KDE, if you want the keypad enter numbers:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there are two options for changing keymaps. [Xmodmap](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xmodmap) is relatively easy to alter, but suffers from being a bit slow to start up. [Xkb](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/X_KeyBoard_extension) is horribly fiddly and terribly documented, but is much more stable and should supposedly replace xmodmap. I use the latter.

Having said that, I'm not sure how easy it is to remap modifier keys with xkb. (FWIW, the KDE system settings are just a frontend to the xorg/xkb options.)

In any case, here is a solution using xmodmap.

Firstly, check the existing mapping.

```
xmodmap -pke
```

You'll see something similar to the following.

```
keycode  77 = Num_Lock NoSymbol Num_Lock
```

You didn't say what key you wanted to swap, so as an example, I'll swap <kbd>a</kbd> with num lock. Hence, also find the line for this key.

```
keycode  38 = a A a A aacute Aacute aacute
```

Run the following commands to test by swapping them immediately.

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode 38 = Num_Lock NoSymbol Num_Lock'
xmodmap -e 'keycode 77 = a A a A aacute Aacute aacute'
```

And you can check the mapping again.

```
xmodmap -pke
```

To make this change permanent, create `~/.Xmodmap` with the following content, then restart (or possibly log out/in).

```
keycode  38 = Num_Lock NoSymbol Num_Lock
keycode  77 = a A a A aacute Aacute aacute
```

Comment: *"You didn't say what key you wanted to swap"*. Really I do not want to swap it I want to prevent it toggling keypad. Because I rarely need to turn off numlock and so I prefer to give NumLock key another functionality and toggle keypad using an option in settings. Numlock can be used as a hotkey. But it toggles keypad even if it is a hotkey. So I thought swapping Numlock with another key may solve the problem.

Comment: @MinimusHeximus That's what I figured. Swapping with `a` was just a simple example, but you can swap with a key that you don't use often if you still require toggling of Num Lock occasionally. Alternatively, you can only change the virtual keymapping of the physical Num Lock key, without swapping another key. If you assign an unused virtual key to the physical Num Lock, then you can assign any shortcut to it in KDE. (Look through `xmodmap -pke` for obscure options, e.g. I don't have a physical key for `keycode  98 = Katakana` or `keycode 158 = XF86WWW`, so these might be useful mappings.)

Comment: I ran `xmodmap -e 'keycode 77 = Katakana NoSymbol Katakana NoSymbol Katakana'`. Now how can I turn off/on NumLock?

Comment: @MinimusHeximus I'm not sure; that wasn't part of your question. :) However, searching the web shows [some](http://superuser.com/a/752834/125959) [options](http://tuxthink.blogspot.com.au/2011/09/enabling-capslock-from-command-line.html). I think you can just switch to a VT (e.g. Ctrl+Alt+1) then use `setleds +num`. If you just want to set it on/off at startup and never touch it again, you can do that in KDE system settings > Keyboard > NumLock on KDE Startup.

Comment: 1. `setleds +num` does not work in a graphical environment. 2. After `xmodmap -e 'keycode 77 = Katakana NoSymbol Katakana NoSymbol Katakana'` NumLock works just for only one time. It turns off Numpad. 3. `Katakana` can be set as a hotkey but the hotkey does not work in KDE environment! (Numlock worked before changing). 4. The effect of `xmodmap` is temporary.

Comment: these are all issues I encountered!!

Comment: @MinimusHeximus I suggest you ask a new question for 1 and 2. For 3 I think you should try other keys instead. For 4, what do you mean by temporary? Are you talking about the `~/.Xmodmap` method in my answer?

Comment: By temporary I mean that it is forgootten after a restart. btw, I will try to swap NumLock with an addtional non-standard key on my keyboard. But I'm not sure if  these additional keys are shown with `xmodmap -pke`

Comment: @MinimusHeximus So again, are you talking about the `./Xmodmap` method in my answer, or `xmodmap -e ...`? I'm not sure how thorough `xmodmap -pke` is, but I tested some keys out that can be assigned as KDE shortcuts: `XF86Mail`, `XF86AudioNext`, `XF86HomePage`. If you don't have keys on your keyboard for "Launch email", "Next track", and "Home", then you could just use these.

Comment: This code is perfect: `xmodmap -e 'keycode 77 = XF86Bluetooth Num_Lock Num_Lock'` keeping Numlock working with `shift` and XF86Bluetooth can be used as a hotkey. But after a restart  `xmodmap -e 'keycode 77 = XF86Bluetooth Num_Lock Num_Lock'` must be run again. I'm thinking about changing things in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols`.

Comment: but still Numlock key turns off keypad even after it is changed. And .Modmap does not make this change automatic.

Comment: in keyboard settings --> advanved --> Miscellaneous Compatibility options --> Numberic keypad keys always enter digit fixes turned off Numlock.  Btw, I could not make this change automatic at startup normally.

Comment: @MinimusHeximus Just to double check, you mention using `.Modmap`, but you know that it's actually `.Xmodmap`? I'm not sure why the system settings change isn't enforced at startup. (Perhaps a bug?)

Comment: xmodmap is good to find keycodes. But to change them I think it's more permanent to modify keyboard layouts (Still I'm not sure how).